# Send multiple http request at same time in php

Tags: php, curl, guzzle6

I am trying to get page `meta tags` and `description` from given url .
I have url array that I have to loop through to send `curl get request` and get each page `meta`, this takes a lot of time to process .

> Is there any way to process all urls simultaneuosly at same time?

I mean send request to all urls at same time and then receive 
response as soon as request is completed respectively.
For this purpose I have used

> curl_multi_init()

but its not working as expected. I have used this example 
[Simultaneuos HTTP requests in PHP with cURL](https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/)

I have also used `GuzzleHttp` example 
[Concurrent HTTP requests without opening too many connections](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/concurrent-http-requests/)

my code

```
$urlData  = [
      'http://youtube.com',      
      'http://dailymotion.com',      
      'http://php.net'     
      ];
foreach ($urlData as $url) {
      $promises[] = $this->client->requestAsync('GET', $url);
}

Promise\all($promises)->then(function (array $responses) {
   foreach ($responses as $response) {
          $htmlData = $response->getBody();
          dump($profile);
   }
})->wait();
```

But I got this error

> Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise\all()

I am using `Guzzle 6` and `Promises 1.3`

I need a solution whether it is in `curl` or in `guzzle` to send simultaneous request to save time .

Comment: php by nature does not do that, you may 1 ) go with this https://github.com/amphp/amp , or use another programming language the suitable with your needs.

Comment: have you checked this https://github.com/amphp/artax ?

Comment: `GuzzleHttp\Promise\all` isnt `Promise\all`. check your namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `use` statements. You probably have a mistake there, because correct name is `GuzzleHttp\Promise\all()`. Maybe you forgot `use GuzzleHttp\Promise as Promise`.

Otherwise the code is correct and should work. Also check that you have `cURL` extension enabled in PHP, so Guzzle will use it as the backend. It's probably there already, but worth to check ;)